# Facebook Login Dialog appears only once

Tags: android, facebook

I am using new Facebook SDK in my application and I am directly using the Login button provided by the apk as -

```
 <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

When I press the  login button, the login dialog appears and when I cancel the dialog it disappears.. this is fine... But when I again press the login button, then It doesnot works .. No error at all is shown in the Log cat.. Please help me to find out the matter..

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show your Activity/Fragment code?

Comment: Nothing in my activity code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the onActivityResult method in your Activity and pass it into the LoginButton instance.

Answer (score 0):

I used `Fragment` in my case and I forgot to set `setFragment()`

So, try this

```
LoginButton mLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
mLoginButton.setFragment(this);
```